# How to configure mutual TLS in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In Hyperledger network I have enabled both TLS and CLIENTAUTH (on peers and orderers, not on CA). But when it comes to submitting transactions via fabric-sdk-node libraries I keep getting errors during verification of client's certificates.

I also tried setting TLS client certificates explicitly but no luck.
https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-mutual-tls.html

peer / order .yaml

```
- name: CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED
  value: "true"
- name: CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE
  value: /shared/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/blockchain-org1peer2.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
- name: CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE
  value: /shared/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/blockchain-org1peer2.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
- name: CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE
  value: /shared/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/blockchain-org1peer2.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
- name: CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTAUTHREQUIRED
  value: "true"
- name: CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS_FILES
  value: /shared/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
- name: CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTCERT_FILE
  value: /shared/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/client.crt
- name: CORE_PEER_TLS_CLIENTKEY_FILE
  value: /shared/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/client.key
```

connection.json

```
{
    "name": "bam-ticketing-network",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Org1",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300"
                },
                "orderer": "300"
            }
        },
        "credentialStore": {
          "path": "./local_fabric/tmp/hfc-kvs",
          "cryptoStore": {
            "path": "./local_fabric/tmp/hfc-cvs"
          },
          "wallet": "wallet"
        },
        "tlsCerts": {
            "systemCertPool": true,
            "client": {
                "key": {
                    "path": "./local_fabric/certs/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/client.key"
                },
                "cert": {
                    "path": "./local_fabric/certs/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/client.crt"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "channels": {
        "channel1": {
            "orderers": [
                "blockchain-orderer1",
                "blockchain-orderer2",
                "blockchain-orderer3"
            ],
            "peers": {
                "blockchain-org1peer1": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "ledgerQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                },
                "blockchain-org1peer2": {
                    "endorsingPeer": true,
                    "chaincodeQuery": true,
                    "ledgerQuery": true,
                    "eventSource": true
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org1": {
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "peers": [
                "blockchain-org1peer1",
                "blockchain-org1peer2"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "blockchain-ca"
            ],
            "adminPrivateKey": [
                "./local_fabric/certs/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore/key.pem"
            ],
            "signedCert": [
                "./local_fabric/certs/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/signcerts/Admin@org1.example.com-cert.pem"
            ]
        }
    },
    "orderers": {
        "blockchain-orderer1": {
            "url": "grpcs://192.168.99.130:31011",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "blockchain-orderer1",
                "grpc-max-send-message-length": 4194304
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "./local_fabric/certs/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/blockchain-orderer1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
            }
        },
        "blockchain-orderer2": {
            "url": "grpcs://192.168.99.130:31012",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "blockchain-orderer2",
                "grpc-max-send-message-length": 4194304
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "./local_fabric/certs/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/blockchain-orderer2.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
            }
        },
        "blockchain-orderer3": {
            "url": "grpcs://192.168.99.130:31013",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "blockchain-orderer3",
                "grpc-max-send-message-length": 4194304
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "./local_fabric/certs/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/blockchain-orderer3.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
            }
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "blockchain-org1peer1": {
            "url": "grpcs://192.168.99.130:30110",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "blockchain-org1peer1",
                "grpc.keepalive_time_ms": 600000
            },
            "clientKey": { 
                "path": "./local_fabric/certs/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/client.key"
            },
            "clientCert": {
                "path": "./local_fabric/certs/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/client.crt"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "./local_fabric/certs/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/blockchain-org1peer1.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
            }
        },
        "blockchain-org1peer2": {
            "url": "grpcs://192.168.99.130:30210",
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "blockchain-org1peer2",
                "grpc.keepalive_time_ms": 600000
            },
            "clientKey": { 
                "path": "./local_fabric/certs/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/client.key"
            },
            "clientCert": {
                "path": "./local_fabric/certs/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/client.crt"
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "./local_fabric/certs/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/blockchain-org1peer2.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt"
            }
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "blockchain-ca": {
            "url": "https://192.168.99.130:30054",
            "registrar": {
                "enrollmentID": "admin",
                "enrollmentSecret": "adminpw",
                "profile": "tls"
            },
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            },
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "path": "./local_fabric/certs/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem",
                "client": {
                    "key": {
                        "path": "./local_fabric/certs/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/client.key"
                    },
                    "cert": {
                        "path": "./local_fabric/certs/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/client.crt"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting this error:

On peer: ERRO 1587b[0m TLS handshake failed with error tls: failed to verify client's certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.17.0.1:62440

On nodejs app: ERRO 11347[0m TLS handshake failed with error tls: failed to verify client's certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.17.0.1:6156

I would expect that fabric client or gateway could provide some option to support mutual TLS or some sample of connection.json.

Answer (score 1):

During troubleshooting I have discovered that fabric-client for some reason doesn't load proper certificate for mutual TLS. The loaded certificate content is different from the one sepcified in "tlsCerts" section of client config. (For more details [bug report](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FABN-1285))

Anyhow, I have manage to resolve loading proper certificate with following workaround where I explicitly set this key and certificate to the client:

```
    const clientKey = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './local_fabric/certs/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/client.key'));
    const clientCert = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './local_fabric/certs/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/tls/client.crt'));

    const gateway = new Gateway();
    const caName = ccp.getCertificatAuthoritiesForOrg(orgName)[0];

    const opts = {
        wallet: wallet,
        identity: identityID,
        discovery: {enabled: false, asLocalhost: false},
        clientTlsIdentity: 'tlsId'
    };

    await gateway.connect(ccp.profile, opts);
    //set TLS certs for CLIENTAUTH
    const client = await gateway.getClient();
    client.setTlsClientCertAndKey(Buffer.from(clientCert).toString(), Buffer.from(clientKey).toString());
```